# Windows 7 password recovery (partially known password)

Tags: windows, forgot-password, password-recovery

I have a problem, on my other computer I had a password consisting of a word and three digits, for logging in to windows 7. I remember the word, however I forgot the digit combination. And since there are only a 1000 combinations so I think I could somehow try these combinations but I don't know how can I do it. I have another computer here which I can make use of.

Thanks for any suggetions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming

Comment: @Clive Could you at least give me a refrence or something?

Comment: It should be easier to just boot a linux live disk and use the "chntpw" utility.

Comment: @Clive - Yes, this question is neither about programming nor about gay marriage.  It should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download Ophcrack. It uses a windows 7 rainbow table to retrieve passwords. I would highly recommend it. Simple to use, just burn iso to a dvd/cd and boot from disk. It'll boot into the linux OS and begin retrieving your password.

[Ophcrack Live CD](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/download.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can restart your computer on safe mode.
 and try to login using the administrator account if is available.
or you can try Linux live to get your password or as i remember (do it on your own risk) you can delete the profile file(SAM..) and restart your PC you will get a windows to set a new password.